# Sum of lag functions

Tags: r, sum, data-manipulation

Within one person's data from a behavioral task, I am trying to sum the clock time at which a target appears (data$onset) and the reaction time of their response (data$Latency) to find the clock time at which they entered their response at. For future data processing reasons, these calculated values will have to be placed in the data$onset column two values down from when the target appeared on the screen. In the example below:

| Item | onset | Latency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prime | 9.97 | 0 |
| Target | 10.70 | 0.45 |
| Mask | 11.02 | 0 |
| Response | NA | 0 |

Onset is how many seconds into the task the stimuli appeared, and latency is reaction time to the target. latency for non-targets will always be 0, as subjects don't respond to them. in the "NA" under onset, I need that value to be the sum of the onset of the target+reaction time to the target (10.70+0.45). Here is the code I have tried:

```
data$onset=if_else(is.na(data$onset), sum(lag(data$onset, n = 2)+lag(data$Latency, n = 2)), data$onset)
```

If any clarification is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you used `if_else` I'm adding a `dplyr` solution;

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
mutate(onset=ifelse(is.na(onset),lag(onset,n =2)+lag(Latency,n = 2),onset))
```

**output;**

```
  Item     onset Latency
  <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Prime     9.97    0   
2 Target   10.7     0.45
3 Mask     11.0     0   
4 Response 11.1     0
```

Also note that, if you want to stick to your own syntax;

```
data$onset=if_else(is.na(data$onset), lag(data$onset, n = 2)+lag(data$Latency, n = 2), data$onset)
```